# Can I mine a block with no transactions other than the coinbase?

Tags: mining-software, empty-blocks

Based on what [I read](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getblocktemplate), there is this script to build the Merkle root

```
import hashlib     
def dblsha(data):      
    return hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(data).digest()).digest()     
 
txnlist = [coinbase] + [binascii.a2b_hex(a['data']) for a in template['transactions']]     
merklehashes = [dblsha(t) for t in txnlist]     
while len(merklehashes) > 1:     
     if len(merklehashes) % 2:     
        merklehashes.append(merklehashes[-1])      
    merklehashes = [dblsha(merklehashes[i] + merklehashes[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(merklehashes), 2)]      
merkleroot = merklehashes[0]
```

I wanted to mine an empty block (a block with only a coinbase transaction in it) , can I modify the script so that `txnlist` only includes coinbase and ignore the other transactions? or it is  considered a hard fork?

```
txnlist = [coinbase]
```

Or this isn't the correct way to mine empty block?

I currently only have a shallow understanding of Bitcoin, that's why I ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

A block is valid even with no transactions other than the coinbase transaction. There have been many such blocks. This is especially true for early blocks of the blockchain.

---

- [Close to 19% of mined Bitcoin blocks were empty](https://www.theblockcrypto.com/linked/1964/close-to-19-of-mined-bitcoin-blocks-were-empty) - Steven Zheng.
  October 17, 2018
- [A total of 71 empty blocks were mined in the first five months of 2020, accounting for 0.3% of the total blocks produced](https://www.theblockcrypto.com/post/67928/bitcoin-miners-are-mining-fewer-empty-blocks-in-2020-and-it-may-not-all-because-of-chance)

[image: Average number of BTC transactions per block] ([source: Cointelegraph](https://cointelegraph.com/news/the-current-state-of-the-bitcoin-network-and-its-biggest-block))